# Package Error with DelimitedFiles

Tags: julia

I try to get to run this example code from documentation ([https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/#DelimitedFiles.readdlm-Tuple{Any,AbstractChar,Type,AbstractChar}](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/#DelimitedFiles.readdlm-Tuple%7BAny,AbstractChar,Type,AbstractChar%7D)):

```
using DelimitedFiles

x = [1; 2; 3; 4];
y = [5; 6; 7; 8];

open("delim_file.txt", "w") do io
    writedlm(io, [x y])
end

readdlm("delim_file.txt", '\t', Int, '\n')
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Module DelimitedFiles not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("DelimitedFiles")` to install the DelimitedFiles package.
Stacktrace:
 [1] _require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:435
 [2] require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:405
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:576
 [4] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [5] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:305
 [6] _start() at .\client.jl:371
while loading E:\Dropbox\computer_sync_hardlink\julia\beispiel\beispiel.jl, in expression starting on line 1
```

and when runng `Pkg.add("DelimitedFiles")`:

```
ERROR: unknown package DelimitedFiles
macro expansion at .\pkg\entry.jl:53 [inlined]
(::Base.Pkg.Entry.##1#3{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at .\task.jl:335
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end() at .\task.jl:287
 [2] macro expansion at .\task.jl:303 [inlined]
 [3] add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at .\pkg\entry.jl:51
 [4] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##3#6{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at .\pkg\dir.jl:33
 [5] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##3#6{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at .\file.jl:59
 [6] withenv(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#5{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String},String}, ::Pair{String,String}, ::Vararg{Pair{String,String},N} where N) at .\env.jl:157
 [7] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at .\pkg\dir.jl:32
 [8] add(::String) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:117
```

I really do not what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the documentation for the development version of julia (note the `/latest/` in the URL), but you are using Julia v0.6 (likely) when you run your code. Here is the documentation that matches your installation: [https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.0/stdlib/io-network/#Base.DataFmt.readdlm-Tuple{Any,Char,Type,Char}](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.0/stdlib/io-network/#Base.DataFmt.readdlm-Tuple%7BAny,Char,Type,Char%7D)

On Julia v0.6 your example works *as is*, if you just remove `using DelimitedFiles`.